# C3.js chart.load not loading for x/y axis graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have set up an xy graph and I'm trying to load in a new dataset but for some reason the data never generates inside the graph:

```
<div id="graph"></div>

<script>
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#graph',
        data: {
            xs: {
                'data1': 'x1',
                'data2': 'x2',
            },
            columns: [
                ['x1', 10, 30, 45, 50, 70, 100],
                ['x2', 30, 50, 75, 100, 120],
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                ['data2', 20, 180, 240, 100, 190]
            ]
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        chart.load({
            bindto: '#graph',
            data: {
                xs: {
                    'data3': 'x3',
                },
                columns: [
                   ['x3', 20, 40, 55, 60, 80, 110],
                   ['data3', 30, 150, 260, 120, 90]
                ]
            }

        });
    }, 2000);

</script>
```

Anyone have any idea why this might be? I know that chart.unload works fine and I've tried playing with adding and removing the bindto: 'graph', but nothing has worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load), the `load` function does not need the *data* parameter, so it should look like this:

```
chart.load({
    bindto: '#graph',
    xs: {
        'data3': 'x3',
    },
    columns: [
        ['x3', 20, 40, 55, 60, 80, 110],
        ['data3', 30, 150, 260, 120, 90]
    ]
});
```

Demo snippet:

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#graph',
        data: {
            xs: {
                'data1': 'x1',
                'data2': 'x2',
            },
            columns: [
                ['x1', 10, 30, 45, 50, 70, 100],
                ['x2', 30, 50, 75, 100, 120],
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                ['data2', 20, 180, 240, 100, 190]
            ]
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        chart.load({
            bindto: '#graph',
            xs: {
                'data3': 'x3',
            },
            columns: [
               ['x3', 20, 40, 55, 60, 80, 110],
               ['data3', 30, 150, 260, 120, 90]
            ]
        });
    }, 2000);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.8/c3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.8/c3.js"></script>

<div id="graph"></div>
```

Comment: That was it - perfect! I was struggling with that for longer than I'd like admit ;)

Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem, sometimes it just needs some fresh eyes.